# Ninject: Intercept by attribute without deriving from InterceptAttribute

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, attributes, ninject, aop

I'm looking for a way to hook up an interceptor to a method call based on a certain attribute using Ninject. Ninject offers the `InterceptAttribute` base class to do so which is neat, however I would like to achieve this with a custom attribute. The reason is that I want to decorate certain domain service interfaces with business related attributes, so I can't have any stuff tightly coupled to a framework in it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could derive from [`InterceptorRegistrationStrategy`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception/blob/46fdb55f8521d6203f39738bd37ffd4f377f2562/src/Ninject.Extensions.Interception/Planning/Strategies/InterceptorRegistrationStrategy.cs) and override the `Execute(IPlan plan)` method (plus probably also `RegisterClassInterceptors`) to use your own attribute types instead of ninject's `InterceptAttribute`.

You would then need to register the implementation as a kernel component:

```
this.Kernel.Components.Add<IPlanningStrategy, MyInterceptorRegistrationStrategy>();
```

You'll probably also have to understand how `InterceptorRegistrationStrategy`, `AutoNotifyInterceptorRegistrationStrategy` and `MethodInterceptorRegistrationStrategy` work so you can create an implementation which works and is side-effect free.
(this does not replace the interception extensions but rather just extends it).

There is also stackoverflow answer covering a custom strategy which might be useful: [Ninject Intercept any method with certain attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386461/ninject-intercept-any-method-with-certain-attribute)

Or of course you could could use one of the other approaches to do interception:

- with a binding, define interception for the whole type like `Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().Intercept().With<MyInterceptor>()` and have the `MyInterceptor` check whether it should intercept a given method or not.
- use conventions API or write something like that yourself, search for all of your custom interception attributes and then use this syntax:

```
Kernel.InterceptAround<CustomerService>(
    s=>s.GetAllCustomers(),
    invocation =>logger.Info("Retrieving all customers..."),
    invocation =>logger.Debug("Customers retrieved"));
```

(also see [Interception with ninject](http://baharestani.com/2013/12/30/interception-with-ninject/))